# How to Access Server and execution environment information ($_SERVER or document root path) from (Custom) PHP Extension

Tags: php

I just started writing my own PHP Extension by following the tutorial at

http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/

And it works great for me.

My problem started when I try to read a file(path relative to calling .php script) using this extension. I observed that the `"Document Root Path"` of the calling .php file and the`executing PHP extension` are `different.`

So:-

1. How to **access the "Document Root Path"** of the calling .php file.
2. How to **access other Server and execution environment information**. (values present in $_SERVER and/or $_ENV)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Server information by checking variable $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

The answer of 2nd question is "its possible but dont do it, it makes your server vulnerable."
For this you can do `http_request()` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-request.php

Write a method at server, with defenitoin just `return $_SERVER;`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, But I think you misunderstood the question. My Code is a php extension written in C++ & compiled by VS2010 into a dll which php loads and exposes the functions to the calling script. Now my C++ code doesn't have a $_SERVER because that is a php code, but yes I want the same data but I need a C++ substitute for the same from PHP ZEND Framework. please do checkout http://blog.slickedit.com/2007/09/creating-a-php-5-extension-with-visual-c-2005/